# How to convert SSID with less than 8 characters to byte[] to be used as salt for Rfc2898 (WPA)?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I'm trying to convert SSID and passphrase to an encrypted WPA key, there is an  implementation I found but not in .NET and fairly complicated. With some research I've found out the class **Rfc2898DeriveBytes** which is almost surely used to create WPA key. The problem is the salt used here is an array of byte while the SSID (I think this is the salt specifically used in WPA) is a string.

If the SSID's length is equal or greater than 8 characters, I can use `UTF8.GetBytes` method to convert it to `byte[]` and used as salt OK. The test showed that it produces the encrypted key as exactly as what the other implementation I found does.

```
var ssid = "mySSID";//this is less than 8 and can cause exception 
                    //later on
var salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ssid);
var wpaEncryptor = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("myPassword", salt, 4096);
var bytes = wpaEncryptor.GetBytes(32);
```

But now if the SSID's length is less than 8 characters, I don't know how to convert it to byte[] (*the salt requires the minimum length of 8*). I think we have to perform some padding algorithm here but not sure how that could be done.

What I found is written in JavaScript, I can of course convert that to C# without much modification but I really would like to use the class `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. If you're interested in the JavaScript implementation, you can look at the page source of this http://jorisvr.nl/wpapsk.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript code you pointed at contains the following snippet:

```js
while (hash.length < 64) {
    /* prepare 20-byte (5-word) output vector */
    var u = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
    /* prepare input vector for the first SHA1 update (salt + block number) */
    i++;
    var w = stringtowords(salt, i);
```

Now as you can see this means that the salt is used directly as an input of PBKDF2 (yes, I followed it from the SSID input variable). Unfortunately that means that you cannot directly use PBKDF2 for salts lower than 8 bytes; the salt is directly mixed into multiple iterations within PBKDF2.

Unfortunately the designer of Rfc2898DeriveBytes - the PBKDF2 API in .NET - considered it as part of his task to build in security constraints into the API. This is not so strange after what happened to their implementation of PBKDF1, but it is perhaps a bit over-zealous.

---

As an alternative you can use [the Mono implementation of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/Rfc2898DeriveBytes.cs) and remove the constraint on the salt size (although, if I'm not mistaken, that constraint is only present on the setter). That should solve the problems at the location where they should be solved.

Comment: Thank you, at least I know there is no way to pad values outside and use that with the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. Just remove the constraints as you said and it works. It's very pity that this way I still have to copy the source code while I like the simplicity of using what built in .NET framework.